# Interpolating rows in GPS data

Tags: excel

I have gps data that is event based, thus, the times/sampling rates are inconsistent. I am trying to fill in the missing times between the records and have the coordinates match the row of the original time.

[Here's what I'm currently observing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UNUp.png)

Simply put, I'm trying to generate new rows between those two times that are sequential and going up by 1 second each row. Is this possible - I am extremely grateful for any help or direction given.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a clear idea of the time step in the data? And up to how many consecutive samples can be missing in an interval?

Comment: For the data I'm working with it is usually inconsistent - since it is event based (new sample is produced based on the number of meters traveled since last data point was recorded).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Time` is in A1 please try:

In E1 `=A2`
in E2 and copied down to suit:

```
 =A$2+(ROW()-1)/86400
```

in F1 and copied down to suit:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,1))+(E2-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)))*(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)+1)-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)))/(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)+1)-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)))
```

(and similar for ColumnG).

Comment: Hey, the first line works perfectly! However, the second line is returning an #N/A in the cell. Do you think this referring to the wrong column?